# Pass parameter to WebAPI through Uploadify

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, uploadify

How do I pass an object from uploadify to webapi controller? I am not sure how to properly use the ScriptData parameter.

I tried this:

```
    $("#fileInput").uploadify({

            'uploader': '/api/files/Addfiles/',
            'swf'       : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'cancelImage' : '/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
            'auto': true,
            'folder': "/uploads",
            'scriptData'     : {'product': null }               
        });
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddFiles(Product product )
    {
    }
```

If I remove the Product parameter from my controller the controller gets called( on clicking "Select Files") and everything works fine. But when I try to pass a parameter it does not get called. My route template is:

```
  api/{controller}/{action/{id}
```

Comment: Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: Okay. After a bit of investigation I found uploadify *will* work happily with an MVC controller action, but does not appear to pass on the scriptData as part of the request URL (according to Fiddler2). My own solution was to combine any extra values into settings.formData and they do get passed.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your WEB API controller action so I can figure out why my test-bed is not working at all for WEB API?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. After a bit of investigation I found uploadify *will* work happily with a standard MVC controller action, but does not appear to pass on the scriptData as part of the request URL (according to Fiddler2).

As an alternative you can modify the formData setting to post back additional information:

### Sample View:

```
<div class="myuploader">
    <input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file_upload" />
    <input id="uploadfiles" type="button" value="Upload files" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.myuploader').uploadify({
            swf: '/content/uploadify.swf',
            uploader: 'home/upload',
            auto: true,
            formData: {product: 456}
            });
```

### Controller upload action:

```
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase oFile = Request.Files["Filedata"];
        if (oFile != null)
        {
            string sDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(oFile.FileName);

            // You can pick up any parameter set in the formData member of the plugin using its name
            string testParam = Request.Form["product"];   // This gets 456

            // Do something with the file here
            return Content("1");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("0");
        }
    }
}
```

### Follow up:

I am still not able to get Uploadify working, at all, with a standard WebApi controller.

*As an aside: As we needed SWF and HTML 5 support we have wrapped uploadify and the commercial uploadifive in our own plugin, which dynamically converts parameters as required by the browser capabilities. We also have it automatically extract any hidden field values and combine them into formData. You may want to try something like that yourself.*